# Trying to load and read images from SD card android

Tags: java, android, image

### What I am trying to do:

I am trying to load all the images that I have onto the phones SD card when the app is created. I then have a button and when I click the button, the next image should show.

### What I've done:

So far I have included this code in the  **onCreate()**  method, however I don't know how to add multiple images into the folder.

```
 File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "uct.png");
    boolean success = false;

    // Encode the file as a PNG image.
    FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

At the moment I have an array of of image IDs, these images are stored in the Drawable folder at the moment.

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4};
```

Then I have an  **onClick()**  method that increments a private index variable to set the Image Resource like so (here imgView is the ImageView).

```
imgView.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
```

### What I don't know how to do:

Firstly, I don't know how to add multiple images to the SD card in the  onCreate() method. Also I am not sure what the best way to go about loading the 'correct' image from the SD when the button is clicked.

I hope this makes sense, please remark if anything needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

If i were in your case,

1. Create the ViewPager to show all images.
2. And you can get all images url using this code.

   ```
       String[] STAR = {"*"};
       ArrayList<String> imageUri = new ArrayList<>();

       Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
               , STAR, null, null, null);

       if (cursor != null) {
           if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               do {
                   String path = cursor.getString(cursor
                           .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

                   Log.i("Path", path);
                   imageUri.add(path);
                   getDate(path);

               } while (cursor.moveToNext());

           }

       }
   ```
3. You can pass the imageUri ArrayList to Viewpager adapter.At viewPager 
   adpter you can use any image library to load image. In case of [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

   Picasso.with(context)
        .load(uri)
        .resize(150,150)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(imageView);